# Create DATETIME Stamp and fill in table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to have a table with the hourly averages of the last 30 days.
This table should be updated by an event every day.
I came up with the following code:

```
SELECT Time(HOUR(TIMESTAMP)*10000) AS Zeit,(AVG(Value1)+AVG(Value2)+AVG(Value3))AS Average
FROM Table
WHERE TIMESTAMP>= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY HOUR(TIMESTAMP)
```

Which gives me a table like this:

```
00:00:00  |  0
01:00:00  |  3
...
23:00:00  | 35
```

What I want is to upgrade my time to a datetime, to have todays date and the 24 hours.
Then I want to put this values into a table. How could I do this?
The result should be:

```
2020-07-29 00:00:00  |  0
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry I totally forgot to mention. I use MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(), MAKETIME(HOUR(TIMESTAMP), 0, 0)) AS Zeit,(AVG(Value1)+AVG(Value2)+AVG(Value3))AS Average
FROM Table
WHERE TIMESTAMP>= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY HOUR(TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: That works great thank you! How would you insert these values into a new table? Simply INSERT INTO?

Comment: Yes, `INSERT INTO your_table (col1, col2) SELECT TIMESTAMP(...`, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html